# OpenJPEG: How to set the stepsizes used for quantization?

Tags: java, jpeg2000

I have a JP2-file that I decompress and want to recompress Using OpenJPEG.
For the original ojp_dump returns:

```
stepsizes (m,e)=(2046,12)
```

The re-encoded imgage has many stepsizes:

```
stepsizes (m,e)=(1824,14) (1776,14) (1776,14) (1728,14) (1792,13) (1792,13) (1760,13) (1872,12) (1872,12) (1896,12) (5,10) (5,10) (71,10) (2003,10) (2003,10) (1890,10)
```

And the recompressed image-file is much larger than the original.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide exact `opj_compress` command line?

Answer (score -1):

Re-compression is known to be a lossy operation. And if you try to crank up the quality during re-compression step to avoid the loss, you end up with a much larger image than the original. That's why re-compression should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: I have to crop and descew the original image, so have have to recompress it afterwards. I tried to recompress the original just to compare the resulting file-size.